# C#で配列を扱うJSONデータのデシリアイズ方法

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

string型の配列データをJSON形式でPOSTリクエスト
受け取り側で受け取ったJSONデータをデシリアライズしてコンソールに表示をしたいです。
どうすればよいでしょうか？
通常の単一データの表示はできます。配列のデシリアイズがわかりません。

**JSON**

```
{
    "Id":["田中", "鈴木"]
}
```

**C#**
"田中" と "鈴木" をコンソールに表示したい

**開発環境**
.NET6.0

Comment: 現在どのようなソースコードであって、どの部分で問題になっているのかなどを追記してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

デシリアライズするクラスのプロパティに`IList`型を指定することで配列データを扱うことができます。

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Sample
    {
        public IList<string> Id{get;set;}
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sample = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Sample>(
            @"{
                ""Id"":[""田中"", ""鈴木""]
            }");
            foreach(var id in sample.Id)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```